# Não consigo instalar/habilitar o Php_soap

Tags: php

Adquiri um VPS na Godaddy e estou bastante satisfeito, porém, não consigo alterar configurações de php. A principal delas é o PHP_SOAP. Ele diz que está instalado, mas meu PHPINFO não mostra e minha aplicação não reconhece o módulo.
O processo todo segue abaixo:

**yum install php-soap:**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 104.219.172.10
 * base: centos.s.uw.edu
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirrors.oit.uci.edu
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.keystealth.org
Nothing to do
```

**yum search php_soap:**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 104.219.172.10
 * base: centos.s.uw.edu
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirrors.oit.uci.edu
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.keystealth.org
=============================================================================== N/S Matched: php-soap ================================================================================
ea-php54-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
ea-php55-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
ea-php56-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
ea-php70-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
ea-php71-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
ea-php72-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

**find -name soap.so:**

Nada acotece. Simplesmente a linha com o IP do servidor e o usuário se repetem para novo comando.

Comment: Qual a versão do php ?

Comment: Faça o seguinte: abra o arquivo php.ini --> descomente ";extension=php_soap.dll" (remover o ponto e virgula). Após isso reinicie o servidor e veja se corrigiu.